# How to display labels on points of a tikz plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm creating a `\begin{tikzpicture}` - unclear if I'm working with tike or pgf or whatever honestly, but I have my data displaying perfectly using `\addplot[my options] coordinates { .. my data here }`.  My problem is that for each point of data, I have a label (unique for each data point) that I want to display.  How do I do this?

So, in this following example, for these 3 points I want them to show the label that is indicated in the comment there.

```
\addplot[color=black,solid,thick,mark=*, mark options={fill=white}] coordinates {
         % /32(h)
         (2211, 1110)
         % x1
         (6164, 4168)
         % x1-PPL18
         (11610, 36335)
        };
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would use the `nodes near coords` feature for this, which allows you to automatically place nodes at each plot coordinate. By default, these nodes will contain the `y` value, but you can change the value to an arbitrary string provided with each point. This is easiest if you use `\addplot table` instead of `\addplot coordinates`, since the input format is less verbose, but you could also do it with `coordinates`.

If you need to adjust the position of individual labels, you can add a new column to your data and make that available to the node options using `visualization depends on=<expression> \as <\macroname>`.

Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,ymin=0,enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.2}]
\addplot[
    black,
    thick,
    mark=*,
    mark options={fill=white},
    visualization depends on=\thisrow{alignment} \as \alignment,
    nodes near coords, % Place nodes near each coordinate
    point meta=explicit symbolic, % The meta data used in the nodes is not explicitly provided and not numeric
    every node near coord/.style={anchor=\alignment} % Align each coordinate at the anchor 40 degrees clockwise from the right edge
    ] table [% Provide data as a table
     meta index=2 % the meta data is found in the third column
     ] {
x       y       label       alignment
2211    1110    /32(h)      -40
6164    4168    x1          -40
6500    4500    x2          160
11610   36335   x1-PPL18    -40
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Some of my figures include points very near each other; I think this would have my labels stomp on each other because of the anchor=-40 degrees - is there a way to specify this with no 'trampling'?  I don't see a way

Comment: You can provide a per-point alignment by adding a new column and using `visualization depends on`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: What about cases where I may need to have the labels be at different distances from the points?  I've actually made up this graph now using Peter's method and I had to significantly shift the x,y values I gave each label. I prefer your way but is there another column of that table that can add distance?

Comment: You can add as many columns as you want, and make each available in the same way as the first. You could add a `padding` column and map that to the `outer sep` in the node style, or you could add an `xshift` and a `yshift` column and map it to the options of the same name.

Comment: @grfrazee: You can add `fill=white, inner sep=1pt` to the `every node near coord/.style={...}`.

Comment: It seems that the alignment column can only contain numeric data. Is it possible to use the 'east' syntax somehow?

Answer (score 14):

Jake's solution is a better, but as an alternative you could add nodes at each of the coordinates:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[color=black,solid,thick,mark=*, mark options={fill=white}] 
    coordinates {
         % /32(h)
         (2211, 1110)
         % x1
         (6164, 4168)
         % x1-PPL18
         (11610, 36335)
        }; 
\node [above] at (axis cs:  2211,  1110) {$32h$};
\node [below] at (axis cs:  6164,  4168) {$x_1$};
\node [left ] at (axis cs: 11610, 36335) {$x_1-PPL_{18}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```