# pgfplots: How to change the alignment of one single node

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display labels on points of a tikz plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47688/how-to-display-labels-on-points-of-a-tikz-plot)

I plot a scatter plot using `pgfplots` and automatically label every single mark with its description. When two marks are too close together, the descriptions overlap. Can I change the alignment of one or more chosen nodes? In the example, I'd like to change node `c` to e.g. `north east`.

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.dat}
x   y   desc
1   1   a
1   1.2 b
1   1.195   c
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[nodes near coords,point meta=explicit symbolic,nodes near coords align={anchor=south west},]
\addplot[scatter,only marks,]   table[x=x,y=y,meta=desc] {test.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Right, that's what I was looking for. Thanks.