# Adding text into diagram

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to add text to my diagram. I tried it with `\node`, but it doesn't work.
What I exactly want to do is, to add concrete numbers of Personalstärke at each coordinate in the diagram.
This is how my diagram looks like:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.9}

\begin{axis}[

    title={},
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel={Jahr},
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
          scaled y ticks = false,
          set thousands separator={},
          fixed},
    ylabel={Personalstärke},
    y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
          scaled y ticks = false,
          set thousands separator={.},
          fixed},
    xmin=2008, xmax=2018,
    ymin=12000, ymax=13200,
    xtick={0, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018},
    ytick={0, 12200, 12400, 12600, 12800, 13000, 13200},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[

    color=blue,
    mark=circle,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (2009,12288)(2010,12433)(2011,12522)(2012,12526)(2013,12416)(2014,12782)(2015,12758)(2016,12813)(2017,12920)(2018,13087)
    };

    
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\caption[Personalentwicklung{Personalentwicklung}

\label{fig:Personalstarke}

\end{figure}
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: \node is the way to go, but you need coordinates.  For example `at (axis cs: 2009,12288)` will place the text at the first point, but you need to be inside the axis environment and it helps to offset the text using [above] or [left] etc.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is what `nodes near coords` is for, so try `\addplot[nodes near coords, ...`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I tried \node[below] at (2009,12288) { text } and I put it before \end{axis} but it didn't work....can't compile it...

Comment: @TorbjørnT. nodes near coords works, but how can I edit the numbers there (I would like to make them smaller, different color, decide myself if above or below, set thousandpoint)... Do you know that?

Comment: For example `nodes near coords style={red, font=\tiny}`. I don't understand exactly what you mean by "set thousandpoint". Here is a method for setting the position of the labels on a per-point basis: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47692/

Comment: as each node is in a different position, I am using now \node. Somehow it is working now. But thank you guys anyway!

Comment: compilation errors often mean missing semicolons.